# Queue does not reveive the last item from threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm having troubles with Python threads and queues. I wrote a worker which does some tasks in a database. Each task comes from a queue. Whenever he's done he should write the final result (rows inserted) to the queue, which is then handled when all tasks are done.

Here's a code sample:

```py
class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue_in, queue_out, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.queue_in = queue_in
        self.queue_out = queue_out
    def run(self):
        while not self.queue_in.empty():
            task = self.queue_in.get()
            table_name, rows_inserted = insert_rows(task)
            self.queue_in.task_done()
            self.queue_out.put((table_name, rows_inserted))

def do_db_stuff():
    queue_in = queue.Queue()
    queue_out = queue.Queue()
    # here I read names of data files, not relevant
    for file in files:
        queue_in.put(file)
    threads = [Worker(queue_in, queue_out) for _ in range(3)]
    for t in threads:
        t.start()
    queue_in.join()
    # queue_out.join() # this ends in an infinite loop when uncommented
    # Here I do some statistics stuff with the items from queue_out
```

Result is that when I put 3 files to be processed from Worker, I only have 2 items in the queue_out. This happens for any mount of files (=tasks), the worker working on the last task cannot put his result to queue_out. And I really do not have any clue why.

I also tried to put a `queue_out.join()` right after `queue_in.join()` but this leads to an infinite loop, which can only be interrupted by CTRL-C:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "testfile.py", line 91, in <module>
    run()
  File "testfile.py", line 72, in run
    queue_out.join()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/queue.py", line 83, in join
    self.all_tasks_done.wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 295, in wait
    waiter.acquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Adding a loop for all threads to join ends in the same problem (infinite loop).

Any ideas how to solve this? Maybe adding a timeout somewhere?

Regards, Thomas

Comment: Left an answer about not being able to reproduce issue. Could `insert_rows` function be non-thread-safe in some way? Like accessing database using shared connection?

Comment: Well, one attribute of the Worker-class is there to hold a connection to a database and then every function is able to use `self.connection`. I had a version before which was working as expected. It was not a threading.Thread subclass, it was a normal worker function. I'm still puzzled, maybe it's too late today for creating solutions. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce this, when just using a placeholder for the `insert_rows` function.

```py
def insert_rows(task):
    sleep(5)
    return 'test', 'tests'


...

for file in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    queue_in.put(file)
...

queue_in.join()
print(queue_out.qsize()) 
# -> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution - it's all about `task_done()`.

`queue_in.join()` waits for all threads to finish their tasks and `task_done()` tells it. Now, when calling `task_done()` too early the last task may want to put an item to queue `queue_out` but at that time all other tasks are already done, the program continues and this one last item is missed.

So I moved `task_done()` at the very last end, right behind after `self.queue_out.put((table_name, rows_inserted))` and - tadaaaa - the item is now in `queue_out` for further processing.